# Which means that there is a zero before the field searched in the select clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to modify an SQL procedure but I can't understand the full query, there is a zero before the field, and I don't know what it means.

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1.id , 0 fiedl
FROM tableX  
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
    INNER JOIN ....
```

Its just an question, I try to find info on microsoft sql server docs but nothing found, about an number before or some index.

Answer (score 2):

It means `fiedl` isn't being retrieved from any table, if such a column even exists.

Instead, the second column is returning a literal `0` for all rows. An alias, `fiedl` has been supplied for this second column.

There are various ways of supplying [column aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

```
column fiedl
column AS fiedl
fiedl = column
```

All of the above specify `fiedl` as an alias for `column`.

---

In this sort of query, it's almost always a case (if you look back through source control) that it used to retrieve a `fiedl` column. At some later point it was decided that the column was no longer required (or was sensitive and shouldn't be shared, etc) but that changing the *callers* of the query was more work than modifying the query to still return a result set with the same shape but no longer retrieving any real data in column 2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - deliberately keeping it.